# Using the same table, why does IN, NOT IN, NOT EXISTS, and EXISTS have different outputs?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH SAMPLE (DATE_OF_USE, VENUE, ROOM_LOG, LOG_NAME, PERSON_LOG) AS
(
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-01', 'ASU', 'Red Room', 'Log 12345', 'Jane, Doe' 
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-01', 'ASU', 'ROOM 01', 'Log 12345', 'Jane, Doe' 
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-02', 'MOR', 'Blue Room', 'Log 67890', 'John, Smith'  
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-02', 'MOR', 'ROOM 02', 'Log 67890', 'John, Smith' 
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-03', 'ASU', 'ROOM 03', 'Log 11222', 'Luis, Jacob' 
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-04', 'MOR', 'ROOM 04', 'Log 22211', 'Patel, Hannah' 
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-05', 'ASU', 'Red Room', 'Log 33333', 'Sparks, Noah' 
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE '2023-09-05', 'ASU', 'ROOM 01', 'Log 33333', 'Sparks, Noah' 
    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    SAMPLE
WHERE 
    LOG_NAME IN (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE 
                 WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
```

Output:

```
 2023-09-05 00:00:00 ASU ROOM 01 Log 33333 Sparks, Noah
 2023-09-05 00:00:00 ASU Red Room Log 33333 Sparks, Noah
 2023-09-01 00:00:00 ASU ROOM 01 Log 12345 Jane, Doe
 2023-09-01 00:00:00 ASU Red Room Log 12345 Jane, Doe


SELECT 
    * 
 FROM 
    SAMPLE
 WHERE 
     LOG_NAME NOT IN (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
```

Output:

```
2023-09-03 00:00:00 ASU ROOM 03 Log 11222 Luis, Jacob
2023-09-02 00:00:00 MOR ROOM 02 Log 67890 John, Smith
2023-09-02 00:00:00 MOR Blue Room Log 67890 John, Smith
2023-09-04 00:00:00 MOR ROOM 04 Log 22211 Patel, Hannah

 SELECT 
    * 
 FROM 
    SAMPLE
 WHERE 
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
```

Output:

```
Blank

 SELECT 
    * 
 FROM 
    SAMPLE
 WHERE 
     EXISTS (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
```

Output:

```
2023-09-01 00:00:00 ASU Red Room Log 12345 Jane, Doe
2023-09-01 00:00:00 ASU ROOM 01 Log 12345 Jane, Doe
2023-09-02 00:00:00 MOR Blue Room Log 67890 John, Smith
2023-09-02 00:00:00 MOR ROOM 02 Log 67890 John, Smith
2023-09-03 00:00:00 ASU ROOM 03 Log 11222 Luis, Jacob
2023-09-04 00:00:00 MOR ROOM 04 Log 22211 Patel, Hannah
2023-09-05 00:00:00 ASU Red Room Log 33333 Sparks, Noah
2023-09-05 00:00:00 ASU ROOM 01 Log 33333 Sparks, Noah
```

Using NOT IN returns the results I need, but I've seen posts that recommend using EXISTS/NOT EXISTS rather than using IN/NOT IN, but I'm not sure why if the operators produce different results. I was expecting NOT EXISTS to return 'Log 67890' twice, 'Log 11222', and 'Log 22211', but the output was blank. I was also expecting EXISTS to return 'Log 12345' and 'Log 33333' twice.

I haven't seen a post that explains the operators when using the same table (in this example, there is only 1 table 'SAMPLE').

In this example, using IN/NOT IN seems to work. However, sometimes I run into this error: 'ORA-00913: too many values"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To paraphrase some of the excellent answers below, if you use `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE EXISTS (xyz)` and the `xyz` part has no "connection" (correlation) to `T1`, then it just boils down to `SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE TRUE` (assuming that there is at least one record in XYZ). Which means just get every record from `T1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subquery

```
SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room'
```

returns four values.

When you do `IN (...)` you are correlating against just those four results - your main query is finding the four rows in `sample` which have those four values.

When you do `EXISTS (...)` you are not correlating. You are finding rows in `sample` where there are *any* rows returned by that subquery. That is an all-or-nothing decision, with the same answer for every row in the outer table. If there are *any* rows with `'Red room'` the subquery returns something and the exists clause evaluates to true; otherwise it evaluates to false.

If you want the same result as `IN` you would have to add correlation within the subquery instead:

```
SELECT 
    * 
 FROM 
    SAMPLE s1
 WHERE 
     EXISTS (
         SELECT NULL -- can be anything as value isn't referred to elsewhere
         FROM SAMPLE s2
         WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room'
         AND s2.LOG_NAME = s1.LOG_NAME -- correlation with main query
     )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yc0A2sU4)

Adding `NOT` would then also give the same result as `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because where conditions are different:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SAMPLE
--  1. rows with LOG_NAMES having ROOM_LOG = Red Room
WHERE     LOG_NAME IN (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
    -- Results with rows having LOG_NAMES (Log 12345, Log 33333) 

--  2 rows with LOG_NAME not having ROOM_LOG = Red Room
WHERE     LOG_NAME NOT IN (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
    -- Results with rows NOT having LOG_NAMES (Log 12345, Log 33333)   --> having (Log 11222, Log 22211, Log 67890) 

--  3    if SAMPLE  have no rows with ROOM_LOG = Red Room 
WHERE     NOT EXISTS (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
    -- Results with no rows because table does contain ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room' 

--  4   if SAMPLE does have at least a row with ROOM_LOG = Red Room 
WHERE     EXISTS (SELECT LOG_NAME FROM SAMPLE WHERE ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room')
    -- Results with all rows because table does contain ROOM_LOG = 'Red Room'
```

All results are exactly as asked for...